# How to distinguish between a correct and a botched unicode encoded string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have string data in various languages where parts of the strings have seen some wrong encoding/decoding while others are correct, I need to fix the wrong ones:

Here's an example for the german word "Zubehör":

```
correct = "ZUBEHÖR"
incorrect = "ZUBEHÃ\x96R"
```

I already found out that I can correct the errors like this:

```
incorrect.encode("raw_unicode_escape").decode("utf8")
```

However using this on the correct strings yields an error. I could iterate over all strings and use a `try`-statement, but I don't know if this will work reliably and I'd like to know a more elegant way.

Also while the `\x96` is written out when printing it's actually only one character:

```
incorrect[-3]
Out[34]: 'Ã'

incorrect[-2]
Out[33]: '\x96'
```

How can I reliably only find those strings that have these odd unicode characters in them like `ZUBEHÃ\x96R`?

EDIT:

Here's something else I stumbled upon while experimenting:

When I do `incorrect.encode("raw_unicode_escape")` then the result is `b'ZUBEH\xc3\x96R'`.

But when I do this with e.g. a cyrillic word like this:

```
"Персонализированные".encode("raw_unicode_escape")
```

Then the result is `b'\\u041f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0441\\u043e\\u043d\\u0430\\u043b\\u0438\\u0437\\u0438\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u043d\\u043d\\u044b\\u0435'`

Why am I getting `\x`-escapes in the first case and `\u`-escapes in the second case while doing the exact same thing?

And why can I `.decode("utf8")` back the `\x`-escapes into a readable format but not the `\u`-escapes?

Comment: Your edit is worth a question of its own, I think it doesn't belong here (now that the first part is answered already). But to give you a few hints: `\xNN` escapes are for codepoints up to 255 (0xFF), `\uNNNN` escapes are for higher codepoints (up to 0xFFFF, beyond that you need `\UNNNNNNNN` escapes). But the reason for `.decode('utf8')` to succeed or not is that the second form actually *contains* escape sequences (you see two backslashes, because the escape sequences are escaped again for display), but the first one doesn't – the byte string `b'\xc3'` doesn't contain a backslash.

Comment: You're right, I'll put this into another question. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the fixes-text-for-you library ([ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/)):

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> ftfy.fix_text("ZUBEHÃ\x96R")
'ZUBEHÖR'
```

It operates line by line, so if you have a string with clean and corrupt strings, but on separate lines, ftfy can probably handle it.

**Note:** This is not an exact science.
The way ftfy works involves a lot of educated guesses.
The tool is very well made, but it may not guess correctly in all cases you have.
If you can, it is always better to fix the errors at the source (ie. make sure all text is correctly decoded in the first place).